# Syntax issue with my for loop and while loop keeps repeating infinitely (python)

Tags: python

I was working on a for loop and while loop for 2 separate programs asking for the same thing. My for loop is giving me syntax issues and won't come out as expected…

***Expectations:*** A python program that takes a positive integer as input, adds up all of the integers from zero to the inputted number, and then prints the sum. If your user enters a negative number, it shows them a message reminding them to input only a positive number.

***reality:***

i1 = int(input("Please input a positive integer: "))

if i1 >= 0:

```
value = 0 # a default, starting value

for step in range(0, i1): # step just being the number we're currently at
    value1 = value + step
print(value1)

else:
   print(i1, "is negative")
```

And my While loop is printing  "insert a number" infinitly…

Here is what my while loop looks like:

```
while True:
  try:
    print("Insert a number :")
  n=int(input())
  if(n<0):
    print("Only positive numbers allowed")
 else:
    print ((n*(n+1))//2)
 except ValueError:
  print("Please insert an integer")
```

`*Same expections as my for loop but as a while loop*

Anyone know anyway I could fix this issue?

Comment: no exit condition...

Answer (score 1):

You have some indentation issues. This way works:

```py
while True:
    try:
        print("Insert a number: ")
        user_input = input()
        if user_input == 'q':
            exit()
        n = int(user_input)
        if n <= 0:
            print("Only positive numbers allowed")
        else:
            print(n * (n+1) // 2)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer")
```

Output sample:

```
Enter a number: 
>>> 10
55
Enter a number: 
>>> 1
1
Enter a number: 
>>> -1
Only positive numbers allowed
Enter a number: 
>>> asd
Please enter an integer
Enter a number:
```

See more about indentation in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation).

Comment: Didn't work keeps repeating contiunsly

Comment: @trustmeidontwannabehere You didn't mention that a program should exit in some condition, so I didn't make it. On what condition should the program exit?

Comment: If the user enters "q" the program should end. My apologies for not mentioning this sooner.

Comment: @trustmeidontwannabehere added it.